# How can I categorize nodes by countries?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, nodes

I have a created a content type "person", added to it custom field "country". I have downloaded the "countries" module and installed it.

I would like to categorize "person" nodes by countries, i.e. by clicking on the person's country, I could see all persons who live in the same country.

I don't think taxonomy could do the trick since I will have to add around 140 vocabulary terms also, node reference seems not to work properly...

Any help?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using views:

1. Create a new view that displays persons.
2. Under "Advanced" add a contextual filter for your country
3. As path use: "my_path/%"
4. All users for country "Belgium" Will be available on "my_path/BE"